# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. The updated data have to be calculated first

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE [price].[dbo].[DataClean]
SET MinPrice = (SELECT 
                    [ID], [Item_Name],
                    MIN([Price]) AS MinPrice
                FROM 
                    [price].[dbo].[MasterItem] with (nolock) 
                WHERE
                    Price IS NOT NULL
                    AND Sold IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY
                    [ID], [Item_Name])
```

Any idea will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: please show your table schema, sample data and the expected result

Comment: `didn't have to calculate`  It's really not clear what exactly you're trying to "calculate". You can help clarify things by posting some sample data and showing what result you expect.

Comment: Get rid of the `with (nolock)` . It's not the automatic "go faster" trick you may have been led to believe and it can lead to using stale data.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The query says something like each price shall be an array consisting of id, item_name and a price. That makes no sense at all. Then, in your subquery you aggregate, but your group contains the table's ID. If you say "aggregate my table so as to get one result row per ID", isn't this just not aggregating at all, but keeping the data as is? The ID *is* the table's unique identifier, as its name suggests, isn't it? One ID = one row? So, please, rather than merely saying "here is my query", tell us what the statement is supposed to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 columns listed in your select statement in the sub query.

But, you are trying to update one column in the target table Dataclean.

Try something like

```sql
;WITH CTE_MasterItem AS (
SELECT 
    [ID]
    ,[Item_Name]
    ,MIN([Price]) AS [MinPrice]
FROM [price].[dbo].[MasterItem] WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE [Price] IS NOT NULL
    AND [Sold] IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    [ID]
    ,[Item_Name]
)

UPDATE [price].[dbo].[DataClean]
SET MinPrice = cte.MinPrice 
FROM CTE_MasterItem AS cte
```

then put a WHERE clause in the UPDATE statement if needed

*I haven't tested this as I don't have SSMS

Comment: I am not well versed with SQL Server's `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE`, but isn't this like a cross join when no where clause is given? That means "put a WHERE clause in the UPDATE statement if needed" should better be "Add the appropriate WHERE clause to the UPDATE statement", because it is definitely needed in order not to end up with arbitrary results. Then, I know you took `WITH(NOLOCK)` from OP's original statement, but we should not encourage this. So either remove it or comment on it.

Comment: Yes, I would usually put a WHERE clause in which is why I mentioned it, I would expect you need one in this query on the basis the OP is trying to get that information in the subquery but ultimately, the question and what is required ain't exactly clear so the OP can make the call.

Comment: As for WITH(NOLOCK) I'm not encouraging it, I just left it in, again the question isn't overly clear but asks about updating records.  I prefer not to use it. 

"try something like" is what I would point to, my answer is more on the idea of aggregate it first in a CTE then UPDATE in a separate statement as they were trying to update one column with 3 columns from the subquery. there is more than one way to do what they are trying to do, subquery being one of them.

Comment: (Edit) ThorstenKettner - In some cases you can update a CTE without a where clause, but yes... this isn't one of them.  It definitely needs a FROM clause containing a JOIN back to the base table on the item.